# C++ Polymorphism problems when casting from void *

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

static DWORD __stdcall startThread(void *);

class BaseClass {
private:

    void threadLoop() {
        // stuff ...
        std::cout << someStuff() << std::endl;
        // stuff ...
    }
protected:
    HANDLE handle;
    virtual int someStuff() {
        return 1;
    }
public:
    friend DWORD __stdcall startThread(void *);

    BaseClass() {
        handle = 0;
    };

    void start() {
        handle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, startThread, this, 0, NULL);
    }

    ~BaseClass() {
        if(handle != 0) {
            WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }
    // stuff
};

static DWORD __stdcall startThread(void *obj_) {
    BaseClass *obj = static_cast<BaseClass *>(obj_);

    obj->threadLoop();
    return 0;
}

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
    virtual int someStuff() {
        return 2;
    };
};

int main() {
    BaseClass base;
    base.start();
    DerivedClass derived;
    derived.start();
}
```

Every instance creates a thread using the WINAPI and the helper function `startThread` which delegates the call back to the method `threadLoop` of the object which created the thread. Now the problem is that `threadLoop` calls an other virtual method, but the polymorphism doesn't seem to work if I create a derived class with an other implementation of the virual method.

Why? How can I fix this?

**Edit**: I updated the code, so the thread doesn't get started in the constructor.

Comment: are you sure you are passing in an instance of the derived class to `startThread()`?

Comment: you know that you can use portable, standardized C++11 threads now? std::async? No need to meddle with proprieary APIs or evil casts...

Comment: @sehe And what makes you think he has access to C++11?

Comment: @Nim how can I test this?

Comment: @sehe I need to use the WINAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, such as you're creating and running the thread while the object is being constructed. That is most definitely a bad design.

A clean design would be to encapsulate thread functionalities in an abstract class called `thread`, and then derive from it, overriding the `run` method, for example:

```
class thread : public noncopyable
{
protected:
    HANDLE m_hthread;
    unsigned long m_id;
private:
    static unsigned long __stdcall start(void* args)
    {
        static_cast<thread*>(args)->run();
        return 0;
    }
public:
    thread();
    virtual ~thread();
    virtual bool start()
    {
        if ( m_hthread != nullptr && isrunning(m_hthread) ) 
        {
           throw std::logic_error("Cannot start thread, as it is already running.");
        }
    m_hthread = ::CreateThread(NULL, 0, start, this, 0, &m_id);
    return m_hthread != nullptr;
    }
    unsigned long get_id() const;
    virtual unsigned long wait();
protected:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};
```

And derived from it:

```
class worker : public thread
{
  protected:
      virtual void run() override;
};
```

And you would use this as:

```
worker workerObject;
workerObject.start();

//do other works here
//maybe create few more threads;

workerObject.wait(); //wait for worker to complete!
```

Comment: I'm not sure that that's a very good design.  Much better, I think, would be a separate `Thread` class, whose constructor takes a pointer to aThreadable` (or `Runnable`, or whatever) object.  (But both work, as long as you don't start the thread in the constructor of the object which contains the code.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Agreed. It is better than the OP. But a much better design requires more thinking and typing, so I avoided it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The recommendation here is much better: http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/prefer-futures-to-baked-in-async-apis/222301165 . .NET design of Thread is class is much better than Java, though there are some issues with Resume functionality.

Comment: It depends on why you're using a separate thread.  Futures are very nice when you're parallizing the calculation of something, but they aren't very appropriate in some other cases (e.g. starting a connection thread in a server).

Answer (score 6):

You're starting the thread before you've finished constructing
the derived object.  This is undefined behavior (since you'll
likely be accessing the object in the new thread while you're
still executing code in the creating thread).  You'll have to
separate construction and starting the thread.

EDIT:

One way of handling this sort of problem:

```
class Threadable
{
public:
    virtual Threadable() {}
    virtual run() = 0;
};

DWORD __stdcall startThread( void* object )
{
    static_cast<Threadable*>( object )->run();
}

class Thread
{
    std::auto_ptr<Threadable> myThread;
    HANDLE myHandle;
public:
    Thread( std::auto_ptr<Threadable> thread )
        : myThread( thread )
        , myHandle( CreateThread( NULL, 0, startThread, myThread.get(), 0, NULL ) )
    {
    }
    ~Thread()
    {
        if ( myHandle != NULL ) {
            WaitForSingleObject( myHandle, INFINITE );
            CloseHandle( myHandle );
        }
    }
};
```

Then have your `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` derive from
`Threadable`, and invoke them as:

```
Thread base( std::auto_ptr<Threadable>( new BaseClass ) );
Thread derived( std::auto_ptr<Threadable>( new DerivedClass ) );
```

This isn't perfect (I don't like more or less unlimited waits in
destructors), but it should be enough to get started.  (Modulo
any typos in the code above—I've not tested it.)

Comment: @Mogria Are you calling `start` from the constructor? If so, you still have the same problem. The point is that the construction of the derived class' sub-object doesn't start until your constructor has finished executing. That means that if you start your thread before the constructor has finished, your derived class may or may not be there when your thread "really" starts - i.e. it becomes a race condition whether it's there or not.

Comment: @rlc no, I called `start` from the main function

Comment: @ric Or expressed in the opposite way: you mustn't start the thread until the constructor of the most derived object has finished.  There are several ways of achieving this: use the `start` method, and require client code to call it once the object has been completely constructed, don't use polymorphism in the thread object, but pass it a pointer to a fully constructed threadable, and some more complex solutions involving templates and multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Mogria Could you update your question to show us exactly what you've done?

Comment: @Mogria Second problem, you're not waiting to destruct until the
thread has finished.  You're waiting in the base class, which
means that the derived class can be (and in a quick trial I just
did, was) destructed before the thread ran.  Same problem in
reverse.  My suggestion is to _not_ make thread polymorphic, but
to have it take a pointer to a polymorphic `threadable`.  (I've
edited my answer with some example code---off the top of my
head, and untested, but you should get the idea.)